# On k-regular functions

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics, numerical-calculus

My father asked me the following question:

A real function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is called $k$-regular if for each $y\in \mathbb{R}$, the equation $f(x)=y$ has precisely $k$ distinct solutions.

1. Show that there are no continuous $k$-regular functions for $k$ even.
2. For each $k$ odd, provide an example of a continuous $k$-regular function.

Solving this question was fairly easy but led me to the following problem:

For each $a\in \mathbb{R}^+$ (including $0$), consider the function $f_a\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}:x\mapsto x+a\sin(x)$. Clearly $f_0(x)=x$ yields a $1$-regular function. Plotting these functions for $a=4$ and $a=5$, it becomes fairly obvious that there should be a value of $4\leq a\leq 5$ such that $f_a$ is $3$-regular. (The value should be 'close' to 4.5 as can be seen on a plot).

How can we prove that such a value exists and is it feasable to accurately find this value? More generally, given $k=2l+1$, for which value of $a$ is $f_a$ a $k$-regular function?

I tried the following wishful thinking: I want that $f_a'(b)=0=1+a\cos(b)$ and that $f(b)=0=b+a\sin(b)$. From this one finds that $b-1=\tan(b)$. According to wolframalpha, -4.53360... is a solution to this equation and thus $a=\frac{-b}{\sin(b)}$ yields a value close to 4.6 which seems like a decent candidate.

Based on the above equations, there are many more candidates but only two solutions two $b-1=\tan(b)$ seem to yield a $3$-regular function $f_a$. I'm not really seeing why these particular values should work and the others fail.

Comment: Correcting my earlier comment, $f_a$ is $3$-regular if $a$ is the unique solution in $(1,\infty)$ to the equation
$$\pi+\cos^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{1}{a}\Bigr)-\sqrt{a^2-1}=0$$
which solves numerically as $a\approx 4.603338849$.

Comment: @quasi: That seems to be a little different from the value that I obtained ($\sim 4.607$). Can you also proof that $f_a$ is indeed $3$-regular for such a value? How do you turn the condition of $3$-regularity for $f_a$ into useful formula's?

Comment: For $a\approx 4.607$, if you plot $f_a(x)$, you'll see it has two zeros on the interval $(4,5)$, hence for that value of $a$, the function $f_a$ has $5$ zeros.

Comment: Yes, I can prove that if a is the unique solution in $(1,\infty)$ to the equation
$$
\pi+\cos^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{1}{a}\Bigr)-\sqrt{a^2-1}=0
$$
then $f_a$ is $3$-regular. For the equation above, a symbolic solution won't be achievable, but of course, one can always solve numerically to get an approximate value of $a$.

Comment: Here's another $3$-regular function:
$$
f(x)=
\left(
\left\lfloor{\frac{x+1}{3}}\right\rfloor
+1
\right)
-
\left|
{\vphantom{{\large{\frac{0}{0}}}}}
3\left\lfloor{\frac{x+1}{3}}\right\rfloor
+1
-x
\right|
$$